# Multiple methods named setDetail: found with mismatched result, parameter type or attributes

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I just ran into a problem when opening an old iOS App with current 6.4 Xcode. I think the app was written under 4.0 before ARC.

So I have the following code and error, which used to run fine without any errors:

```
@interface TripV1 : NSObject

@property (nonatomic) int detail;
```

Method

```
-(void)onBooking {
    self.data = [[TripV1 alloc] init];
}
    - (void)setDetailType:(int)type {
        [self.data setDetail:type]; //ERROR is thrown in this line
    }
```

Error:

```
ERROR: Multiple methods named 'setDetail:' found with mismatched result, parameter type or attributes.
```

Any ideas on how I can solve this issue?

Comment: Can you post mode code? All occurrences of `setDetail:` in the project, this file the class for `self.data` anything? :)

Comment: Please show the property declaration for `data`. Is it typed to `id`?

Comment: did some editing in the code above.

Comment: search throughout the project if you really have the same method/property defined somewhere